# WAR files behaves differently which are build by INTELLIJ IDEA and MAVEN WAR Plugin

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, birt, maven-war-plugin

I am trying to migrate Eclipse JAVA EE Web Application to Maven project.

My project has Eclipse BIRT dependency and Eclipse BIRT releases are not mavenized. Therefore, i added all BIRT jar files locally in pom.xml file and i copied them into WEB-INF/lib path

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
   <artifactId>icu</artifactId>
   <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/com.ibm.icu_58.2.0.v20170418-1837.jar</systemPath>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works fine when i create war file by using INTELLIJ IDEA(I mean i am adding to deploy configuration a before launch step as 'Build x.war artifact'.)

However, i encounter a different issue. When maven build goal is added to deploy configuration, i am getting BIRT Engine error(see below). I track nearly all related records since i couldnt fix it.

*What am i missing in maven configuration?*

**Project Tech Info:**

App Server: Wildfly 14

Java Version: Java EE 8

Dependencies:

EclipseLink

Eclipse BIRT

Firebird 3

**MAVEN Build Setting:**

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>org.apache.commons.codec, org.apache.commons.cli, org.apache.commons.logging, org.apache.lucene, org.apache.xerces, org.apache.xml-resolver, org.apache.xerces, org.apache.log4j</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <webResources>
                        <webResource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.xml</include>
                                <include>*.rptdesign</include>
                                <include>*.rptlibrary</include>
                                <include>*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </webResource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**ERROR**

```
02:24:11,265 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
02:24:11,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2396)
02:24:11,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
02:24:11,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
02:24:11,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.example.jsf.reporting.ReportEngine.report(ReportEngine.java:150)
02:24:11,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.example.jsf.reporting.ReportEngine.report(ReportEngine.java:93)
02:24:11,266 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
02:24:11,267 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,268 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
02:24:11,269 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
02:24:11,269 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,270 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53)
02:24:11,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
02:24:11,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,271 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
02:24:11,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:362)
02:24:11,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
02:24:11,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
02:24:11,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
02:24:11,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
02:24:11,273 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,273 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
02:24:11,273 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,273 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
02:24:11,274 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,274 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
02:24:11,274 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,274 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
02:24:11,275 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,275 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
02:24:11,275 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:106)
02:24:11,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
02:24:11,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
02:24:11,277 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,277 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
02:24:11,277 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,277 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
02:24:11,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
02:24:11,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
02:24:11,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
02:24:11,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
02:24:11,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
02:24:11,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
02:24:11,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
02:24:11,282 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
02:24:11,283 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.example.jsf.reporting.ReportEngine$$$view6.report(Unknown Source)
02:24:11,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.example.jsf.reporting.ReportingServlet.doGet(ReportingServlet.java:27)
02:24:11,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
02:24:11,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
02:24:11,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
02:24:11,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
02:24:11,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
02:24:11,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
02:24:11,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
02:24:11,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
02:24:11,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
02:24:11,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
02:24:11,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
02:24:11,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
02:24:11,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
02:24:11,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
02:24:11,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
02:24:11,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
02:24:11,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
02:24:11,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
02:24:11,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
02:24:11,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
02:24:11,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
02:24:11,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
02:24:11,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
02:24:11,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
02:24:11,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
02:24:11,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
02:24:11,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
02:24:11,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
02:24:11,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
02:24:11,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
02:24:11,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
02:24:11,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
02:24:11,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
02:24:11,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
02:24:11,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
02:24:11,291 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
02:24:11,292 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
02:24:11,293 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
02:24:11,293 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
02:24:11,293 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
02:24:11,294 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
02:24:11,294 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
02:24:11,295 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
02:24:11,296 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
02:24:11,296 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
02:24:11,296 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
02:24:11,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
02:24:11,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
02:24:11,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
02:24:11,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
02:24:11,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
02:24:11,297 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/css/CSSValue
02:24:11,298 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.parser.ReportParser.parse(ReportParser.java:177)
02:24:11,298 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.getReport(ExecutionContext.java:2229)
02:24:11,307 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportExecutor.<init>(ReportExecutor.java:86)
02:24:11,307 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:107)
02:24:11,307 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    ... 115 more
02:24:11,308 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.css.CSSValue from [Module "deployment.example.war" from Service Module Loader]
02:24:11,308 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
02:24:11,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
02:24:11,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
02:24:11,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
02:24:11,309 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    ... 119 more
```

Comment: Should it be `<systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.icu_58.2.0.v20170418-1837.jar</systemPath>`?

Comment: It is. i copied in a fuzzy tryouts. <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu</artifactId>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.icu_58.2.0.v20170418-1837.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I just added below dependency to pom.xml. However, i dont understand why Intellij behaves differenyly...

 

<dependency>

            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>

            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>

            <version>1.4.01</version>

        </dependency>